# How does "apt-get install" work to download a file?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, apt

I have recently started using Ubuntu and am confused as to how the Linux package system is run and operated. Does a company (i.e. Canonical or Azure (if you are using WSL)) own and run the package installing servers, or is it community-based like a torrent if you know what I mean? I can imagine the server resources would be very expensive.

Answer (score 2):

There is an archive for Ubuntu packages located at https://packages.ubuntu.com/.
Normally you can see the sources you are currently using in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` as described in the [official manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/sources.list.5.html).

Answer (score 1):

The servers are called `package repositories` and some of them are already added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or similar file by the creators of your linux distridution (in your case, Ubuntu). You can freely add new repositories hosted by other companies and individuals to your list or remove existing ones.